# Question about class/module

Tags: php

```
define('', 'http://' . Config::get('url.help'));
```

Where is it pulling url.help from?

Is this a class or a controller?

What is "Config::get"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a public [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method (`get()`) on a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) (`Config`) and the `::` is called [Paamayim Nekudotayim or the Scope Resolution Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

`url.help` will most likely be `explode()`d on the `.` dots and used to return a value from an array like the following:

```
$config['url']['help'];
```

The values in `$config` are most likely taken from a plain text configuration file such as XML, YAML or PHP INI style configuration.

Comment: Where would I go to edit this? Any idea? classes/Config.class.php sound right?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was Config.php

Comment: UserService::getInstance()->    Where would this be? This isn't a class is it? Is this a module?

Comment: `getInstance()` looks like a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in the `UserService` class so you would need to look at `classes/UserService.class.php` would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

The framework or application you are using must provide :

- A **class called `Config`**
- Which contains *(at least)* a **`static` method called `get`**

For more informations, you should read the [Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) section of the PHP manual.

Not sure where the corresponding URL is defined, but I would bet that the value for `url.help` is taken from some configuration file, or some configuration table in your database.

To know how to edit that value, you'll have to find out how to configure your framework/application -- which probably mean reading its documentation *(that is specific to your application/framework, and we cannot just guess)*.

*As a sidenote : [`define()`](http://www.php.net/define) expects the name of a constant as a first parameter, and not an empty string.*